# Select a random file fairly from nested directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file structure that looks something like this

```
main_directory
+-subdirectory1
  +-file1
  +-file2
  +-file3
+-subdirectory2
  +-file4
  +-file5
+-subdirectory3
  +-file6
```

I want to write a function, that gets the path to `main_directory` and returns one of the files at random, but with each file being equally likely. The nesting level of all files is the same and I can know in advance how deeply they are nested, though ideally I'd prefer to have a solution that works for all cases.

I know that I can use `random.choice(os.listdir("/path/to/main_directory"))` to get a random subdirectory, and I could repeat that recursively until I have a file or something, but that would, for example, make `file6` a lot more likely than all the other files.

Comment: Why not build a list of all eligible files, then pick randomly from that?

Comment: Use resevoir sampling (Knuth's "algoritm R") See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67215172/905902

Answer (score 2):

`glob` does the recursion for you when you include `/**/` as part of the pattern.

```
from glob import glob
from random import choice

random_file = choice(glob(f'{main_directory}/**/*'))
```

If you want to be more specific, use a more specific glob pattern, such as `**/*.log`, or filter the list of files `glob()` returns in another way.

Answer (score 0):

*nesting level of all files is the same and I can know in advance how deeply they are nested*

In such case you might harness [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) for example if files are just in subdirectories of current working directory you might do:

```
import glob
import os
import random
files = [i for i in glob.glob("*/*") if os.path.isfile(i)]
randomfile = random.choice(files)
```